# Load only a specific line

Tags: io, octave

I have a data file containing over a million lines consisting of 16 integer numbers (it doesn't really matter) and I need to process the lines in Octave. Obviously, it's impossible to load the whole file. How can I load only a specific line?

I have thought of two possibilities:

- I have missed something in docs of Simple I/O
- I should convert the file to be a CSV and use some of the csvread features

Comment: Is it an arbitrary line in the middle of a file?

Comment: Yes, it is. The point is to make a cycle through the lines instead of loading the whole file.

Comment: So you just want to do something line by line?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to iterate through the file, line-by-line, you can open the file and then use `fscanf` to parse out each line.

```
fid = fopen(filename);

while true
    % Read the next 16 integers
    data = fscanf(fid, '%d', 16);

    % Go until we can't read anymore
    if isempty(data)
        break
    end
end
```

If you want each line as a string, you can instead use `fgetl` to get each line

```
fid = fopen(filename);

% Get the first line
line = fgetl(fid);

while line
    % Do thing

    % Get the next line
    line = fgetl(fid);
end
```